# How to configure libcurl to use a custom CA bundle when downloading over HTTPS in R

Tags: r, ssl, https, certificate

I'm trying to configure R so that it can download files (and by extension packages) from an HTTPS server that uses a self-signed SSL certificate. The [documentation for `download.file`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/utils/versions/3.6.2/topics/download.file) implies that, when using libcurl, a custom CA bundle can be configured with the `CURL_CA_BUNDLE` environment variable. However, the [documentation for curl](https://curl.se/docs/sslcerts.html) itself only mentions this environment variable in relation to the CLI tool, not libcurl.

It is possible that R is reading the environment variable and configuring libcurl accordingly, however, attempting to download a file with the environment variable set to the path of a working CA bundle file still results in an SSL error, as if the CA bundle is not being used. This suggests that the R documentation is wrong when it talks about the `CURL_CA_BUNDLE` variable in the context of libcurl.

```r
download.file('https://self-signed.badssl.com', destfile='~/.test.html', method='libcurl')
```

```
trying URL 'https://self-signed.badssl.com'
Error in download.file("https://self-signed.badssl.com", destfile = "~/.test.html",  :
  cannot open URL 'https://self-signed.badssl.com'
In addition: Warning message:
In download.file("https://self-signed.badssl.com", destfile = "~/.test.html",  :
  URL 'https://self-signed.badssl.com/': status was 'SSL connect error'
```

Is it possible to specify a custom CA bundle for use by R's `download.file` function when using the libcurl backend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows? `{curl}` [Proxies and Certificates on Windows Networks vignette](https://jeroen.cran.dev/curl/articles/windows.html) provides few extra hints, to use `CURL_CA_BUNDLE`, *libucurl* SSL backend should be set to *OpenSSL*, default in Windows is *Secure Channel* . So yet another env. var to take care of: `CURL_SSL_BACKEND=openssl`

Tested with (renv) project, environment variables configured in project's `.Renviron` file.

```r
Sys.getenv(c("CURL_SSL_BACKEND",  "CURL_CA_BUNDLE"))
#> CURL_SSL_BACKEND   CURL_CA_BUNDLE 
#>        "openssl" "badssl_com.crt" 

# the one without parens is active backend
curl::curl_version()$ssl_version
#> [1] "OpenSSL/1.1.1m (Schannel)"

download.file('https://self-signed.badssl.com', destfile='~/.test.html', method='libcurl')
#> trying URL 'https://self-signed.badssl.com'
#> Content type 'text/html' length 502 bytes
#> downloaded 502 bytes
```

###### `.Renviron`

```
CURL_SSL_BACKEND=openssl
CURL_CA_BUNDLE=badssl_com.crt
```

###### `badssl_com.crt`

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```